# async function - data functions should return an object?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, async-await, vue-component

Why we can't use async with the data function but it is ok with other functions? For example:

```
export default {
  data: async function () { // not ok
    return {
      item: null,
    }
  },
  beforeMount: async function() { // this is ok
    let result = await axios.get('./data-social.json')
    this.item = result.data
  },
  mounted() {
  },
}
```

I will get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `async` before a function transforms it into a function that returns a  `Promise`. `data` method must return an `object` and not a `Promise`.

```
async function myFunction () { [code] }
```

is equivalent to

```
function myFunction () { 
    return Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            resolve((function () { [code] })());
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

I suggest that you remove the async steatment.